# Proposal of a new tag for Sugar, SoaS and OLPC related questions

Tags: feature-request, tags

I am surprised that there is no tag like `sugar` for questions related to Sugar, Sugar on a Stick (SoaS), One Laptop Per Child (OLPC) and anything that has anything to do with these awesome projects.

At the moment you can run Sugar on Ubuntu, Arch, Debian, Fedora and many more.

This is an overview of what Sugar is:
[image: Sugar taxonomy]

Here are some links for reference:

- GitHub organisation: https://github.com/sugarlabs/
- Official website of Sugar: https://www.sugarlabs.org/
- Sugar wiki: http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Welcome_to_the_Sugar_Labs_wiki
- Sugar on a Stick website: http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Sugar_on_a_Stick
- Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_(software)
- OLPC homepage: http://one.laptop.org/
- Try Sugar online (its called *Sugarizer*): http://sugarizer.org/

---

It turns out that although the Sugar environment is appearing from time to time in questions or answers, the only questions related with Sugar directly are:

- [Unable to run Sugar on Arch Linux due to PyGIWarning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246118/unable-to-run-sugar-on-arch-linux-due-to-pygiwarning)
- [How to make a TP-LINK TL-WN321G wireless card work? (Sugar on a Stick, Fedora 23)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245285/how-to-make-a-tp-link-tl-wn321g-wireless-card-work-sugar-on-a-stick-fedora-23)
- [How to remove the return code from the terminal prompt in Sugar on a Stick?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244994/how-to-remove-the-return-code-from-the-terminal-prompt-in-sugar-on-a-stick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the one answer states, there's simply never been any questions on any of these things, or the issues that were raised with respect to these technologies were not at the root cause of any questions that would've merited tagging it with one of these technologies.

Tags server only to categorize things, they're not intended to be exhaustive per SE site. So you'll never find a SE site where tags have been arbitrarily loaded into an SE site in anticipation that they'll then get used down the road. Tags are dynamic and ebb and flow as the questions drive the need for them to exist.

If you start asking questions that merit the use of such tags then create them and they'll then exist at that point when they're actually needed.

But don't simply tag something with these tags if the root cause of the issue has nothing to do with these technologies. That's not their intended purpose.

For example, if you're running on Ubuntu, and are having an issue with Systemd, don't merely tag the question as Ubuntu, since that doesn't really have anything to do with the issue being highlighted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tag for sugar, simply because nobody have ever had a question about diabetes ;).